# Theme XML and CSS has stopped working (default_head_blocks.xml)

Tags: magento2, theme

Working on a custom theme, has been working fine all day.

I did make an alteration earlier in the day (folder name change) and yes, everything did blow up.

I since reverted that change, reloaded everything and all was fine.

Then a few hours later, all custom theme CSS failed to load (for example, the theme's default_head_blocks.xml is no longer working at all).

I came across the bug on loads of posts online about needing to change the theme type from `1` to `0` and mine has indeed changed to `1` but resetting this back to `0` has made no difference.

I have since ran the upgrade, compiled and cleared cache commands etc (numerous times).

(Bear in mind, that this was working fine all day and even after I reverted the folder name change).

I am absolutely stumped right now on what else to try as this has now cost me about 2 hours.

Comment: It's now started working after about the 4 millionth attempt at messing about with commands!

Comment: Now all my theme LESS files are not being compiled (but the XML is loading) - FFS!

Comment: try running the commands with -vvv you might get some error messages

Comment: @iphigenie tried this and it just seemed to list every file it processes and that's many thousands of lines, no error messages that I could see but I'll play around with it a bit more.

Comment: yes, you'll get a scrolling list of every file it processes for every theme in the chain, but sometimes you'll get a small set of lines in red (at least in my shell) in the middle of it.

Comment: @iphigenie ah the only red errors I get were there already (that's a different issue to sort out though, hah) - thanks.